# mysql Foreign key References syntax errors

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  body TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

I can't seem to get the FOREIGN key to work on this statement. I keep getting the error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ch eck the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version  for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REF ERENCES user(id) )
>   AUTO_INCREMENT = 1' at line 6

Comment: There is no semi colon after the primary key....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add comma after Primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  body TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: in addition to the comma I had to reference (table).(column)               `CREATE TABLE comments (
  id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  body TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES blog.users(id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a comma after PRIMARY KEY and changed REFERENCES to db.table(column)

`CREATE TABLE comments (
  id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  body TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES blog.users(id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`